# How to transform preg_replace() to preg_replace_callback() with multiples calls?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have this line of code:

```
$from_uk_name = preg_replace("/^_/", "", preg_replace("/([A-Z]{1})/e", "'_'.strtolower($property_name[1])", $from_name))
```

But since I move the server to PHP 5.5.22 and `preg_replace()` is deprecated I need to move that line into `preg_replace_callback()` but has not idea since there are nested `preg_replace` calls, can I get some advice?

Comment: Seems pretty similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29240611/3933332 don't you think too?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, you're right, but I deleted that post after read the ones leaves by the user and not get the way to do this, for that I ask for someone to help me

Comment: Why didn't you undeleted your old question, maybe rewrite it a bit and explain that the links provided didn't helped you?

Comment: @Rizier123 not at all, I'm confused because those post talks for just one to one replacement I mean `preg_replace` to `preg_replace_callback` but in my case there are nested `preg_replace` and there is where I'm lost

Comment: ^^ Add such stuff in your question to show the guys here where you are confused/stuck and where you need help

Comment: Also try this: `$from_uk_name = preg_replace("/^_/", "",
    preg_replace_callback("/([A-Z]{1})/", function($m){
     return "'_'" . strtolower($m[1]);
    }, $from_name));` Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: Yes @Rizier123 but you should place an answer instead a comment so I can set the question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241033/how-to-transform-preg-replace-to-preg-replace-callback-with-multiples-calls?noredirect=1#comment46695480_29241033) requested:

This should work for you:

```
$from_uk_name = preg_replace("/^_/", "",
            preg_replace_callback("/([A-Z]{1})/", function($m){
                return "'_'" . strtolower($m[1]);
            }, $from_name));
```